# Getsnackbar is not working in bottomsheet in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
static void showSuccessSnackBar(String message, {Color? color, int? secondsToDisplay}) {
    if (!Get.isOverlaysOpen) {
      GetSnackBar(
        backgroundColor: color ?? Colors.green,
        duration: Duration(seconds: secondsToDisplay ?? 3),
        isDismissible: false,
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
        borderRadius: 10.r,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.w, vertical: 15.h),
        snackStyle: SnackStyle.FLOATING,
        messageText: CustomText(
          message,
          isCentered: true,
          maxLine: 5,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          fontFamily: fontSemiBold,
          fontSize: 14.sp,
          textColor: white,
        ),
      ).show();
    }
  }
```

Above code is for snackbar. I have made method of snackbar so I can use it in my entire project. But it is not working in bottomsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isOverlaysOpen also returns true on bottom sheets. See the implementation:

```
  /// Returns true if a Snackbar, Dialog or BottomSheet is currently OPEN
  bool get isOverlaysOpen =>
      (isSnackbarOpen || isDialogOpen! || isBottomSheetOpen!);
```

Comment: Where should I put this ?

Comment: @wolfsoftDeveloper look at your code. You already have it there. Your entire function is wrapped with it. Remove the check and it will work. The reason it doesn't work is because you do this if-check